# How to create perfect css squares in flexbox without using :after

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There seems to be a problem in this next piece of code. Testing on Chrome, there is a difference of just .5 px between height and width, but when switching to device mode, the difference gets bigger (almost 10px). I do have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` set.

What I need: perfect squares and perfect circles. Flexbox is used and I don't want this :after fix used to create perfect squares. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
    max-inline-size: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.oc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.ic {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.lc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    border-radius: 25%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    block-size: calc(50vw - 52px);
}

.abc {
    font-size:90px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .abc {
        font-size: 180px;
    }
    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .oc {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .ic {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-basis: 100vw;
    }

    .lc {
        block-size: calc(33vw - 46px);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .lc {
        block-size: calc((1440px / 3) - 46px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="oc">
   <div class="ic">
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">C</div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="ic">
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="lc">
         <div class="abc">C</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the scrollbar is included in the vw unit

Comment: Thank you for your reply but according to the specs, the viewport relative length units do not take scrollbars into account (and in fact, assume that they don't exist). [link]https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gh9swkfb/ <-- notice the horizontal scrollbar generated because 100vw consider the width of the vertical one

Comment: Strange thing is that it's just the other way around. Desktop mode does have a scrollbar and works like it should, device mode does not have any scrollbar and is displaying the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to use the padding trick but it's the way to go. Your calculation won't be accurate using `vw` unit because you need to account for the scrollbar width

```css
body {
  max-inline-size: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.oc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.ic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.lc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 25%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}
/* this will do the trick */
.lc .abc::before {
  content:"";
  padding-top:100%;
}
/**/
.abc {
  font-size: min(90px,18vw);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .abc {
    font-size: 180px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .oc {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .ic {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="oc">
  <div class="ic">
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ic">
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you insist on using `vw` you need to adjust the code like below. Notice how you will have perfect square but I had to hide the scrollbar to get the result:

```css
body {
  max-inline-size: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.oc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.ic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.lc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  border-radius: 25%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1;
  block-size: calc(50vw - 2px); /* remove only margin */
  box-sizing:border-box; /* you don't have to care about padding and border*/
}

.abc {
  font-size: 90px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  flex: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .abc {
    font-size: 180px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .oc {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .ic {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
  }
  .lc {
    block-size: calc(calc(100vw/3) - 2px);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .lc {
    block-size: calc((1440px / 3) - 2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="oc">
  <div class="ic">
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ic">
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lc">
      <div class="abc">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but as asked I don't want to use any :after or :before. In your solution you still use the padding trick.

Comment: @Jeffrey I know, *you* don't want but it's the way to go. Actually the padding trick is the solution. You didn't explain why you cannot use it. Until then I should give it as a solution because it's the logical one

Comment: Because there is another way to do so and I'm looking for that way :) I know (and already did use) this solution works too, but it is not the answer to my question. I'm explicitly looking for the workaround without the padding hack

Comment: @Jeffrey check the update to understand that what you want to do is not the way to go

Comment: I didn't have to remove the scrollbars here but just used the border-box and changed the margin values that were extracted within the calc and works like a charm now.

Comment: @Jeffrey you have to remove scrollbar because you won't have perfect squares everywhere, it may only work for few cases

Comment: @Jeffrey if the answer solves your issue don't forget to accept otherwise let me know if you still have issues